# Updating variables in PHP after declaring them once

Tags: php

Is it possible to update variables in PHP?

Like declare the variable in the head of the file, and then inside a switch case update the variable?

I'm trying to get it so that it changes the page in the title as so [Website] - [Page visiting [Eg. Home/About Us/Contact Us]]

Comment: You will have to dig deeper into how client server technology works in a web surrounding. You do not want to change a variables value, but most likely the value of a dom object inside a browser. For this you need client side scripting, e.g. javascript.

Comment: [http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: This is why you should show us what you've tried. If you had in fact tried anything, the answer would probably have been apparent to you immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If it wasn't then it would be a constant, not a variable.

```
$variable = "new value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

```
$title = "Our Website";

...

switch($section)
{

    case 'home';
        $title .= " - Homepage";
        break;

    case 'awesome';
        $title .= " - Awesome";
        break;      

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `global` keyword like so:

```
$var = "Original Title";
function changeTitle(){
    global $var;

    if("Condition"){
        $var = "New Title";
    }
}
```

Any reference to that variable will be to the global one then. You can now call this function in your switch case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and in fact one of the common patterns that PHP developers use.

e.g.

```
<?php

$pageTitle = "Home";

switch ($_GET['show_page']) {
  case 'contact':
  $pageTitle = "Contact Us";
  break;

  default:
  $pageTitle = "Home";
  break;
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $pageTitle ?></title>
...
```